# bloom-release fails to open a PR on rosdistro with token error related to workflow scope

Tags: ros, bloom-release

I have 2FA enabled so I'm using bloom with a token.

I've setup github to be forwarded to ssh as recommended here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36500841/604099

And I've setup token based authentication following: http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/GithubManualAuthorization#Token-based_authentication specifically with only "public_repo" scope.

However I'm getting an error

```
! [remote rejected]     bloom-rosdoc_lite-0 -> bloom-rosdoc_lite-0 (refusing to allow a Personal Access Token to create or update workflow `.github/workflows/build_test.yaml` without `workflow` scope)
```

Should I be adding workflow scope to the access token?

Answer (score 2):

No you should not add more scope to your token!

Bloom opens this pull request using your personal fork of rosdistro

```
https://github.com/$USER/rosdistro.git
```

It will use the default branch. (usually master)

If your branch is out of date enough there may be changes on ros/rosdistro:master and the attempted PR from the API will not change the `workflow` directories. However, the presence of those workflow folders in the diff before it is collapsed is enough to trigger the access control limitations of your token.

To resolve this issue you need to make sure that the default fork of your branch of rosdistro is up to date. I did the following:

```
git clone git@github.com:$USER/rosdistro.git
cd rosdistro
git pull git@github.com:ros/rosdistro.git master
git push
```